# Why there is no separated Book in bible for Jesus?

Tags: bible

We have books by Moses, Books for Wisdom, Books for Gospels etc.....

Why there is no separate Book written about Jesus.

Comment: Four Gospels share the opinion about Jesus and is way of life

Comment: That is true - but what point are you making?  What question are your asking?

Comment: I have edited, only to remove capitals, which many feel are indicative of typographical 'shouting'.

Comment: @JohnVissers Based on your comment above, are you asking why there is no book of the Bible *written* by Jesus?

Comment: The **whole Bible is about Jesus.** From Adam's sin, God's plan for Redemption was set in motion. It continues to this day, through the Catholic Church.

Answer (score 3):

Jesus said this in John's gospel:

> 31 If I alone bear witness about myself, my testimony is not true. 32
>   There is another who bears witness about me, and I know that the
>   testimony that he bears about me is true. 33 You sent to John, and he
>   has borne witness to the truth. 34 Not that the testimony that I
>   receive is from man, but I say these things so that you may be saved.
>   35 He was a burning and shining lamp, and you were willing to rejoice
>   for a while in his light. 36 But the testimony that I have is greater
>   than that of John. For the works that the Father has given me to
>   accomplish, the very works that I am doing, bear witness about me that
>   the Father has sent me.

Jesus accepted the Jewish view that He must not testify about himself, but have others testify to who he was and the veracity of what he said. Thus John the Baptist and later the Apostles testified about Jesus. Also his miracles testified about who he was. It was like Jesus was on trial, and he needed witnesses.

However, there is a sense in which it can be said that Jesus DID write the gospels. When you receive information today, how do you get it?

- Reading books and magazines
- Reading websites and phone apps
- Listening to radio
- Watching TV
- and many other mediums of communication

Jesus wrote his gospel on the hearts of his disciples and all who heard him. He spoke words and they were recorded in their memories. A book cannot speak for itself, but a person can help the hearer understand and can answer questions. Writing his gospel on human hearts was a more durable and expressive medium than paper, which of course followed.